# Writing an if-then statement in R for colors in a map plot using the map package

Tags: r, arguments

```
allc <- file.choose()
allcrd <- read.csv(allc)
allcrd
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
data <- (allcrd)
colnames(data) <- c("longitude","latitude")
map('world',
    col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05,
    mar=rep(0,4),border=0, ylim=c(-80,80) 
)
points(x=allcrd$longitude, y=allcrd$latitude, col=???, cex=.5, pch=16)
```

The data being used has specified continents of each data point. I want to make a point yellow if, in Africa, dark blue is in Americas, green if in Asia, light blue if in Europe, and purple if in Oceania.

I need to write an if-then statement to coordinate the color of the points with the specified continent.

Comment: Hi @skylar gay, did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(1:5))
plot(x = df$x, y = df$y, type = 'p')
points(x = df$x, y = df$y, col = ifelse(df$x < 3, "red", ifelse(df$x > 3, "green", "blue")))

# Or assign colors from a dataframe field
df$col <- ifelse(df$x < 3, "red", ifelse(df$x > 3, "green", "blue"))
points(x = df$x, y = df$y, col = df$col)
```

Assuming continent is an attribute of your dataset called `a`

```
col = ifelse(x$a == "Africa", "yellow",
   ifelse(x$a %in% c("North America", "South America"), "blue",
          ifelse(x$a == "Asia", "green",
                 ifelse(x$a == "Europe", "lightblue",
                        ifelse(x$a == "Oceania", "purple", "black")))))
```